# Как в telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI) обрабатывать разными функциями одни и те же текстовые сообщения?

Tags: python, telebot

Например, после разных вопросов пользователь будет тыкать "да" или "нет".

Как обрабатывать его ответы той функцией, которой нужно? У всех функций одна и та же обертка `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`.

И все они запускаются, если текст, на обработку которого они написаны совпадает.

Более подробно данный вопрос раскрыт здесь: [Как переключать функции обработчики текстовых сообщений в telebot python?](https://toster.ru/q/491038)

Comment: https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter11.html

Answer (score 1):

Привет может быть мой ответ будет немного расплывчатым, но я попытаюсь подтолкнуть тебя на путь истины.

В telebot есть очень удобная вещь под названием последовательность, сам недавно узнал.
Выглядит она так:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) # Наша условная точка входа команда /start
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, """\
Приветственное сообщение.
Как тебя зовут?
""")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step) # process_name_step функция к которой перейдёт бот при получении ответа от юзера
def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        name = message.text # тут хранится наш ответ, дальше можно его обрабатывать
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Сколько вам лет?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step) # преходим к новой функции, туда можно передать тот же ответ что и в прошлой, но обработать можно будет по другому
```

Пример взял и расписал отсюда https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py, из официального репозитория. Надеюсь помог решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос и вы просто хотите обработать ответ одним и тем же хэндлером, то просто сделайте это через инструкцию if:

```
if message.text == 'Да':
    # нужная функция 
elif message.text == 'Нет':
    # нужная функция
```